# Go to keyframe of Spritebuilder timeline

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I have a timeline where I basically want the user to have the ability to tap on the screen to fast forward the animation (well, more like skip part of the animation) to a later part. Obviously, this would have to be done using code.

I've researched this quite a bit and I don't think there's an easy solution. `CCBSequence` and `CCBSequenceProperty` offer a bit of hope, but my ideas have run dry and can't see a way to do it.

Obviously I'm aware of the animation manager and using it to run timelines and stop timelines, or even call something when the timeline is completed, but my capabilities with manipulating timelines made in Spritebuilder doesn't extend too far beyond that.

I can think of a messy workaround, where basically I just duplicate the section of the timeline I want to skip to and when the screen is tapped stop the current timeline and go to that, but it seems cumbersome and messy and I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the easy solution after a bit more looking

So if you have a look in CCAnimationManager there is a method for this called:

```
- (void)jumpToSequenceNamed:(NSString*)name time:(float)time;
```

So with your node you can call

```
[node.animationManager jumpToSequenceNamed:@"MyTimeline" time:1.0]; // 1 Second
```

Answer (score 0):

If your animations aren't extremely complicated, try to implement it via cocos2d actions http://www.cocos2d-swift.org/docs/api/index.html
Using engine API you can create animation with custom speed on every tap.

Comment: Thanks, probably the best way to go about it in retrospect, although it was a fairly complex animation.